# PostgreSQL function return multiple distinct types

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-optimization

is it possible for a function to return multiple distinct types?

Example:

I have following tables: `games`, `games_rounds` and `games_players`

Now to load a full game by it's `id` i need to first load it from `games` and then load all rounds from `games_rounds` by doing `where game_id = $1` and then do the same for `games_players`, that's 3 distinct calls to the database, can this be somehow optimized into a function?

Simple demo:

```
// Basic schema (all game_id rows have an index on them):
    
create table games (id serial, state smallint, value int);

create table games_rounds (id serial, game_id int, outcome int);

create table games_users (game_id int, user_id int, order int);

// Example query to get full game data:

select id, state, value from games where id = 1

select id, outcome from games_rounds where game_id = 1

select user_id, order from games_users where game_id = 1
```

As you can see above `games_users` and `games_rounds` are many-to-one in a relationship to `games`, the queries are simplified in real application there are many more rows and some joins

Comment: that's all looks like one simple query , please provide sample data for each table and desired output

Comment: @eshirvana i have edited the post to add example query and schema, afaik this cannot be done in one query due to the many-to-one relationship of games_users and games_rounds

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this is what you want to do , you can use `refcursor`

```
create procedure getGamedata(gameid int,result_one inout refcursor, result_two inout refcursor, result_two inout refcursor, result_three inout refcursor)
as
$$
begin
  open result_one for 
    select id, state, value from games where id = gameid;

  open result_two for 
    select id, outcome from games_rounds where game_id = gameid;

  open result_three for 
    select user_id, order from games_users where game_id = gameid;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks but like i described there can be multiple games_users and games_rounds for one game, both of them already join from different tables as well, my concern with your approach is that if there is like 20 rounds and 6 players, wouldn't that return like 120 rows that i would then need to reduce and remove duplicates?

Comment: @Dr.ink , refresh